# Custom view Translate animation is not working inside recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, translate-animation

I have a custom view and i have added translate animation on initiate (onLoad). Its working fine when that view is used normally.
But when the view is used inside recycler-view Row layout that animation is not happening properly. Some of the bottom Row having that custom view  not showing translate animation. Below code is written in init block. And Recyler-view in implemented as usual.

```
init{
    Handler().postDelayed({
        val anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, 
                       R.anim.translate_alert_to_left)
        startAnimation(anim)
    }, 50)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @luciano for Edit

Answer (score 1):

I'd need to see more of your code but I assume the `init` block is the one in your custom view.
It shouldn't really be there, try putting it in `onBindViewHolder` might do the trick, but if you should only start an animation when you need it rather than in when the View is created

Comment: I want to see view sliding whenever view is visible first time on the screen. It could   be inside recycler view or without recycler view. So binding animation to recycler view makes no sense.

Comment: So I added translate animation when view is loaded inside init block.

Comment: In that case, you can override onAttachedToWindow() in your CustomView and do you animation here

Comment: I want animation to occur only once, Also onAttachedToWindow() is breaking my view inside recyclerview